# list of  elements, scrolled  elements to the right

Tags: list, function, scroll, shift

Write a function that takes two arguments — a list  and a number
 and returns a list of  elements, scrolled  elements to the right (elements,
those at the end of the list are placed at the beginning). If  < 0, the shift must be to the left.

(For example)

```
In [1]: lrot([1,3,4,2,7,5], 2)
Out[1]: [7,5,1,3,4,2]
In [2]: lrot([1,3,4,2,7,5], -2)
Out[2]: [4,2,7,5,1,3]
In [3]: lrot([1,3,4,2,7,5], 7)
Out[3]: [5,1,3,4,2,7]
In [4]:
```

I will be really greatful for any help!

Comment: This sounds like a homework question; see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @peacetype, Yes, it was really an exercise from previous home assignment, and now i am trying to understand how i could deal with this task. Kind regards, Vend.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/reversal-algorithm-right-rotation-array/amp/) help? I'm not sure about negative `n`.